# how to apply tinyscrollbar.js functionality on two grids on same page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinyscrollbar

I am Creating Asp.Net MVC 4.0 Web Application in which i have to use tinyscroller.js via bootstrap.

I have two grid on same page,now i have to apply scroll functionality on both grid.For this on both grid's div i have to give Id "scroll bar".(which is not valid two id's on same page).

However it working fine for one div but not for second.                                                                   Please suggest what should i do?

Currently my div id is scroll bar so i am using function

```
$('#scrollbar').tinyscrollbar();
```

what should i do for second grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$('.scrollbar').tinyscrollbar();
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="scrollbar"></div>
```